# Pyspark json array string to columns

Tags: arrays, json, pyspark

One of the columns have the following string value. I need to convert it into columns using pyspark

columnName

{"data": {"address": {"city": "Dallas", "state": "Texas", "street1": "1234 23rd St", "zipCode": "98765"}, "cardAlias": "My Card1", "storeName": "DFW Store", "cardNumber": "123456789", "storeNumber": "20"}}

How can I split the string into multiple columns? I am interested in columns:

city, state, street1, zipCode, cardAlias, storeName, cardNumber, storeNumber

with values

Dallas, Texas,  1234 23rd St,   My Card1,   DFW Store,  123456789,  20

Comment: I would use [explode function](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.functions.explode.html) or [example](https://sparkbyexamples.com/pyspark/pyspark-explode-array-and-map-columns-to-rows/)